# You have held packages error when trying to install e17

Tags: apt, enlightenment, held-packages

I received the following error when trying to apt-get install e17 (enlightenment window manager):

```
curios:~$ sudo apt-get install e17
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
e17 : Depends: libedje-bin but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I then ran apt-get update and upgrade and then finally ran apt-mark showhold but the latter exited with no information.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by attempting to install the dependencies. I had to repeat this several times until I encountered a package called libembryo0; e17 was attempting to install "libembryo-bin." I apt-get removed libembryo0 and reattempted to install e17 and it worked. Very sloppy, but successful.
Thank you.